# Use RPM to add rsyslog rule

Tags: centos, rsyslog, rpm

I'm using an RPM to install a binary and some config files to CentOS. My issue is that I need to find a way to set up the rsyslog rules during the RPM install. Up until now I've just been adding the lines manually myself near the top of the file. Other than just adding the lines in using sed in the spec file, what options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your rsyslog.conf:

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Then have your rpm drop a file into that directory.

Comment: Reference: [$IncludeConfig](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_includeconfig.html)

Comment: What if I didn't have access to the rsyslog.conf file other than through the rpm package?

Comment: Rebuild the package to include the directive if it doesn't already.

Comment: I'm saying how would I add the $IncludeConfig line to rsyslog.conf via the rpm package? sed?

Comment: The idea is that you don't have to.  You have that line in there already and your new rpm that wants to add a rule simply drops a file into the /etc/rsyslog.d/ directory.  I suppose you could write a script using awk/sed/grep/etc to check for the existing directive and add it if it's not found, but I find it *very* bad practice to modify files owned by other RPMs.

Comment: This is what I ended up using in the spec file %post:

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using in the spec file %post:

```
if grep -q "MY_SERVICE" /etc/rsyslog.conf
then
        echo "do nothing"
else
        mv /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.conf.orig
        sed -e'/^#### RULES/a :syslogtag, contains, "MY_SERVICE" \/var\/log\/MY_SERVICE.log\n\& ~' /etc/rsyslog.conf.orig > /etc/rsyslog.conf
fi
service rsyslog restart
```